# Python problem with checking and filling 2D-list in a loop with True and False

Tags: python, algorithm, sudoku

so I have a function `generateSudoku()` which should check my 2 Dimensional List which goes from [0][0] to [8][8] (81 fields), and fill in the fields with random numbers by following the rules of a sudoku game which is checked by `kontrolleFeld()`

`kontrolleFeld()` checks if the random generated number fits in to the field. If `kontrolleFeld()` is true then it goes on to the next field to check and fill in a number up to  field [0][8] and then it starts from the next "row"( [1][0] ) to check so that it should check up all fields up to [8][8]. If its false then it checks the same field again with another int number.

but something is unfortunately wrong because sometimes it checks up to 2nd row and stops sometimes 3rd row and stops and sometimes only 1st row.

the `kontrolleFeld()` function which gives back True or False is working flawless. This isn't the problem. (I tested it with already given sudoku)

```
def generateSudoku():
    xcount = 0
    ycount = 0
    while xcount !=9:
        if ycount == 9:
            xcount = xcount +1
            ycount = 0
        else:
            while ycount !=9:
                zrand = random.randint(1,9)
                if kontrolleFeld(xcount,ycount,zrand):
                    s1[xcount][ycount]=zrand
                    ycount = ycount +1
```

Comment: What do you think happens to `ycount` when `kontrolleFeld` returns `False`?  More importantly, what *doesn't* happen to it?

Comment: @ScottHunter my thought was if it returns False it will loop again through the ```while ycount !=9``` and pick a new random int. I don't exactly now the order python goes if something in a while is not True. Does it start again from the upperst line of the function or does it loop again the while code?

So if ```kontrolleFeld()``` returns False then ```ycount``` isn't incremented and it should go again to check the same field till it finds a fitting ```zrand``` from random

Comment: How can you guarantee that there is *any* value that can be legally put in the current cell?

Comment: the ```kontrolleFeld()``` checks if there is already the same number of zrand existing in the same row and column -> if yes it returns False. and then it checks if there is the same number in the same 3x3 block and if not it returns True else it returns False

Comment: I didn't ask what it did; I asked how you can guarantee that there exists a legal value for a  given cell.  If you can't (hint: you can't), then that loop will never terminate.

Comment: ok, now I got what you mean. You're right

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the first 2 rows of your grid have been filled in as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 1 2 3 ?
```

There is no value that can legally replace the ?, so your `while True` loop will never terminate.

Comment: Yes, this. I can't find a solution for this. I tried to reset the fields to 0 and do the function that many times till it will fill all fields but this doesn't work. I can't get a solution for this.

Comment: Your greedy algorithm is fundamentally flawed.  So it either needs to be more careful about what it assigns, or you allow for assignments to be undone.  Also, you'd be better served when making a choice to determine all of the legal candidates & randomly choosing from that list.